# How can I sum the outputs of a function in a loop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, sum

I am trying to simply sum all of the "LengthofRoute" numbers for iterations 1 to 1000, so I can then calculate the average LengthofRoute over the 1000 iterations. How can I do this? I have scoured the internet and cannot find the correct procedure. Dijsktra1 executes and returns an integer normally less than 4.

```
J=0;
f = 0;
nf = 0;
while J<1000
    LengthofRoute = [];
    B = RandomMatrix(0,1,10,10);
    J=J+1;
    [LengthofRoute, RouteTaken] =Dijkstra1(B, 10, 1);

    if LengthofRoute > 0
        f = f + 1;
        % number of feasible occurrences
    else 
        nf = nf + 1;
        % number of nonfeasible occurrences
    end
    LengthofRoute = LengthofRoute + LengthofRoute
end
```

Comment: Now you're calculating `LengthofRoute` everytime afresh using `Dijkstra1()` and storing twice its value in `LengthofRoute` at the end of every iteration. At the start of the next iteration you clean it out again. To stick with your current implementation, you might want to use a running sum that you initialize outside of the loop (e.g. `LORrunning = 0`) and add `LengthofRoute` to that at the end of every loop: `LORrunning = LORrunning + LengthofRoute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use a separate accumulator for summing `LengthofRoute`:

Assume `LengthofRouteSum` is accumulating the sum.

1. Initialize `LengthofRouteSum` before the loop: `LengthofRouteSum = 0;`
2. Accumulate `LengthofRoute` at the bottom of the loop: `LengthofRouteSum = LengthofRouteSum + LengthofRoute;`

The following code should get the job done:

```
J=0;
f = 0;
nf = 0;
LengthofRouteSum = 0;
while J<1000

    B = RandomMatrix(0,1,10,10);
    J=J+1;    
    [LengthofRoute, RouteTaken] =Dijkstra1(B, 10, 1);

    if LengthofRoute > 0
        f = f + 1;
        % number of feasible occurrences
    else 
        nf = nf + 1;
        % number of nonfeasible occurrences
    end
    LengthofRouteSum = LengthofRouteSum + LengthofRoute;
end
```

Comment: it worked the first time, but now for some reason it keeps summing to infinity. Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to amend the if statement to be if LengthofRoute == Inf, then it is infeasible!